# Different Projections on Resource and Item Endpoints in Python Eve

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

I'm fairly new to RESTful API. So please bear with my ignorance.

Suppose I have a MongoDB collection `foobars` with some documents. The structure is like:
`[{'_id': 1, 'foo': 1, 'bar': 1}, {'_id': 2, 'foo': 2, 'bar': 2},...]`

I want to set up two endpoints:

- `GET /api/foobars`,
  this should return a list of `_id`, i.e `[{'_id': 1}, {'_id': 2}]`.
- `GET /api/foobars/1`, this should return a single document whose `'_id'==1`, i.e `{'_id': 1, 'foo': 1, 'bar': 1}`.

I set up a projection in the domain

```
DOMIAN = {
    'foobars': {
        'schema': {...},
        'datasource': {
            'projection': {'_id': 1}
        }
    }
}
```

This works as expected on the Resource level. But on Item level it still only returns the projected fields.

How should I define the projection properly? Should I set multiple endpoints for the same resource? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a workaround. Perhaps not the RESTful way as it seems redundant.

```
DOMAIN = {
    'foobar_list': {
        'schema': {...},
        'datasource': {'source': 'foobars'},
        'projection': {'_id': 1}
    },
    'foobar_item': {
        'schema': {...},
        'datasource': {'source': 'foobars'},

        # Disable resource level endpoint
        'resource_methods': [],
    },
}
```